# Queue transactions support for NodeJS client

Tags: transactions, queue, hazelcast

I have a two parts question:

1. When will NodeJS client module support Queue transaction contexts?
2. If that is not any time soon, is there a work around that we
   can implement similar logic.

I basically want to support the edge case when the slow consumer crashes or takes too long to complete. I would like to able to detect that and re-queue the task.

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround if using just NodeJS client. The behavior you've mentioned can be achieved only with transactions as it's the only way to achieve atomicity of several operations.

Answer (score 0):

We have just added this to our Node.js Client 0.9 roadmap. We expect it would be released in the next couple of months. Thank you!